# why receiver not getting emails using Nodemailer?

Tags: node.js, email, smtp, nodemailer

In the console I can see:

> Sending message <c188880-8889928-1149-89243441014@example.com> to <example@gmail.com>

This is how I'm configuring the transport:

```
nodemailer.createTransport({
    name: "mail.example.com",
    host: "mail.example.com",
    port: 587,
    secure: false, 
    auth: {
      user: "reminders@example.com",
      pass: PASSWORD, //
    },
    logger: true,
    tls: {
      rejectUnauthorized: false,
    },
  });
```

`transporter.sendMail()` function gives me this data:

```
{
  accepted: [ 'example@gmail.com' ],
  rejected: [],
  envelopeTime: 2111,
  messageTime: 842,
  messageSize: 28925,
  response: '250 OK id=198wlQ-exatqE-Lz',
  envelope: {
    from: 'reminders@example.com',
    to: [ 'example@gmail.com' ]
  },
  messageId: '<ccddd9-8311-795e-00c1-7a43f27b6b70@example.com>'
}
```

It used to work, I don't know what's changed.

I've checked the spam/junk folders in the receiver's account.

Comment: If there is no error, the problem is probably not in your code.

Comment: The code seems fine and if the SMTP server accepted the request, but doesn't relay it the problem is not in this code but with the SMTP server. I don't know which service you are using (or if you have a self-hosted SMTP server). But your server may for instance have been blacklisted, and thus all mails from your server will be rejected. If you have access to the mail-server's logs, check them.

Answer (score -1):

Try this instead:

```js
let transporter = nodemailer.createTransport(({
  service: "Outlook365",
  host: "smtp.office365.com",
  port: "587",
  tls: {
    ciphers: "SSLv3",
    rejectUnauthorized: false,
  },
  auth: {
    user: "reminders@example.com",
    pass: PASSWORD, //
  }
}));
        
let info = {
  from: 'reminders@example.com',
  to: `${email}`,
  subject: "Subject text",
  html: `text`
};
        
transporter.sendMail(info, function (err) {
  if (err) {
    console.log(err);
  } else {
    res.json({ message: "Message sent" });
  };
});
```

Comment: What if OP does not have an office365 account?

Comment: You can simply change the service typing "Gmail" instead of "Outlook365" for example. It depends on what email client you're using.

Comment: Still, you should explain WHY your answer presumably solves OP's problem and WHAT is different from OP's code ...

Comment: Honestly, I don't know exactly what's wrong in the OP's code. I used the Nodemailer this way and it worked for me. Just wanted to be helpful. :)

Comment: @MedHmema thnx for the help, and this code was hosted and working for the last 2 month and now it's not working